# The given assembly name or codebase, ''System.Data.SqlServerCe', was invalid. cant figure out why

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I spent the last four hours trying to figure out what's wrong here, and I even saw an example doing exactly the same thing and it still does not work!

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = book.sdf");

            try 
            {
                conn.Open()
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }
            catch 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, insanely simple, I'm new to C# and only need to use it for a small console application to interact with an SQL Server Compact Edition database.

But I cant figure out why is that not working?

What am I missing?

It's worth noting that whenever I take the line

```
 SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = book.sdf");
```

out, it's not breaking which means that whenever I try to access `System.Data.SqlServerCe` it breaks, but I did get intellisense after adding the dll.

I'm so confused. It's worth noting that I am using Visual Studio 2003 (Compact edition requirements) if that changes anything.

Comment: Did you dowload the library? See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Comment: It's downloaded already (someone 15 years ago used it to build an application here so I assume its already on this server somewhere.), so I tried adding the reference by right clicking > add reference >  browse > select that dll.

Keep in mind this is SQL Compact Edition 3.0, which is pretty old.

The dll path on the original project is: "c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\CompactFrameworkSDK\v1.0.5000\Windows CE\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll"

Comment: You cannot use the device binaries on your desktop

Comment: @ErikEJ Oh really?
So how did the developer that worked on that application managed to convert the SQL Database to an SQL CE database programmatically? (.sdf file)

I need to find a way to convert an sql database into an .sdf file, and it needs to run everyday.

Do you have any solution?
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You need the desktop runtime to open a 3.0/3.1 database on your desktop.

Comment: A possible solution is to use Export2Sqlce to generate scripts, and then use a build of SQLceCMD that works with 3.1 to create and populate the file.

Comment: @ErikEJ I'll take a look on how SQLceCMD is made!
Also, is there really no way to populate an sql ce server through a console application?
My main goal is to create an sdf file based on data from an sql server, but I just cant seem to find a proper solution!

Yours looked like the only one, and then it didnt work aswell.
I know it's old but I assumed there's going to be just a little bit more support...

I have also seen you use the same reference on  your sqlCeCmd, and I am at loss, how did you manage to get it working?

Comment: You need to check installed software to see if Net 2003 is installed. Also check if the CE dll is in the folder

Comment: Happy to offer consultancy services, you get 1 hour if you sponsor me on GitHub 

Comment: SQLceCMD is a console application, and can populate a SQL CE database, so yes, there is a way.

Comment: @ErikEJ I tried briefly scrolling through SQLceCMD source code but could not find anything that would explain why I could not spot differences, what if I downloaded the SQL CE compact 2005 (3.1), will that work on a desktop console app? Will that even be compatible with 3.0?

Comment: It sounds like you are lacking some understanding of some concepts. As mentioned, happy to provide consultancy assistance. Yes, 3.1 and 3.0 is the same file format.